# Is there a workaround for using jaeger 4.0.0 with pyinstaller(python3.7)?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, opentracing, jaeger

Unfortunately, I'm not able to use PyInstaller with `jaeger`. The problem is some sort of a thrift error between PyInstaller and `jaeger`.
Like discussed [here](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-python/issues/165).

Are they any workarounds or fixes?

I have tried it with python 3.6 and the newest jaeger-client. 
There I get an Errno 2 -> Even I don't even use a Config file

```
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "jaeger/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "jaeger/core/configuration.py", line 74, in get_config
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/.../PycharmProjects/untitled1/dist/app/jaeger/core/../etc/jaeger.yml'

[6348] Failed to execute script app
```

```py
from quart import Quart
import uvicorn as uv
import logging
import time
from jaeger_client import Config

app = Quart(__name__)


@app.route('/')
async def root():
    return 'Hello world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_level = logging.DEBUG
    logging.getLogger('').handlers = []
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', level=log_level)

    config = Config(
        config={  # usually read from some yaml config
            'sampler': {
                'type': 'const',
                'param': 1,
            },
            'logging': True,
        },
        service_name='your-app-name',
        validate=True,
    )
    # this call also sets opentracing.tracer
    tracer = config.initialize_tracer()

    with tracer.start_span('TestSpan') as span:
        span.log_kv({'event': 'test message', 'life': 42})

        with tracer.start_span('ChildSpan', child_of=span) as child_span:
            span.log_kv({'event': 'down below'})

    time.sleep(
        2)  # yield to IOLoop to flush the spans - https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-python/issues/50
    tracer.close()  # flush any buffered spans
    uv.run(app)
```

The script runs as expected -> Spans are created and web server starts.
Only in the executable, it does not run. And shows the following error:

```
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "jaeger/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "jaeger/core/configuration.py", line 74, in get_config
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/.../PycharmProjects/untitled1/dist/app/jaeger/core/../etc/jaeger.yml'

[6348] Failed to execute script app
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PyInstaller can't resolve [`jaeger_client`](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-python) import. So an easy way is to just edit your spec file and add the whole `jaeger_client` library as a [`Tree`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes) class:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['script.py'],
             ...)
a.datas += Tree('<python_path>/Lib/site-packages/jaeger_client', prefix='./jaeger_client')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
...
```

And generate your executable with `pyinstaller script.spec`.